# Designing Fashion Stationary Brand - Commercial Font use

Tags: fonts, typography, legal

I'm in the preliminary stages of producing a fashion stationary brand with a view to create notepads, organiser sheets, journals, list pads etc.

What considerations do I need to take into account for the use of fonts?

I'll be using Adobe InDesign and have lot's of fonts to choose from including some that I have downloaded for free and some that I have synced from Typekit.

I've done some research and can see there is a difference between fonts and typeface. I've read some info on using fonts/typeface being ok for commercial use if the font files themselves are distributed but when you package the design and send to the printers it does send the font file.

Can anyone help with some more info? Specifically for the use of selling printed materials or selling designs to retailers?

Comment: You may need to add which country you're in. Licensing and copyright arrangements differ.

Comment: related http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/what-could-happen-if-a-corporation-was-using-a-font-commercially-with-out-a-lice

Comment: The first thing you need is to learn the difference between stationAry and stationEry.

Comment: This isn't legal advice, just general advice. But generally speaking, if you use a font—pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Typeface vs. Font.** The first term focusses on the design, the second refers to the files you use, but the terms are often simply used interchangeably.

**Your legal questions**. There are no general answers for this. Each font (even the free ones from Google Fonts for example) come with a license and you need to check that license to see what you are allowed to do with the fonts.